# Segmentation fault while trying to return a pointer to object from a method

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, segmentation-fault, g++

g++ throw me 'segmentation fault' while I'm trying to return an object of a classB from a method of a classA. I don't know how to fix this error, if anybody can tell me why this error happens, I would be grateful. 
So... here is the code:

> classA.h

```
#include "classB.h"
#ifndef _CLASS_A_H_
#define _CLASS_A_H_
class ClassA{
private:
    int id;
    ClassB *ptr_classB;
public:
    ClassA();
    ClassA(int id, std::string name);

    inline void setID(int id){this->id = id;}

    inline int getID(){return this->id;}

    inline ClassB getClassB(){return this->ptr_classB;}

};

#endif
```

> classA.cpp

```
#include "classA.h"
#include "classB.h"

ClassA::ClassA(){
    this->id = 0;
    ptr_classB = new ClassB();
}
```

> classB.h

```
#ifndef _CLASS_B_H
#define _CLASS_B_H

class ClassB{
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    ClassB();
    inline std::string getName(){return this->name;}
};
#endif
```

> classB.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include "classB.h"

ClassB::ClassB(){
    this->name = "default";
}
```

> main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "classA.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ClassA *ptr_classA = new ClassA();

    cout << ptr_classA->getClassB().getName()  << endl;
    //asd

    return 0;
}
```

> Makefile

SRC = src

INC = include

OBJ = obj

BIN = bin

LIB = lib

CXX = g++

CPPFLAGS = -c -I$(INC)/ -std=c++11

all: $(BIN)/main

$(BIN)/main: $(OBJ)/main.o

```
$(CXX) -o $(BIN)/main $(OBJ)/main.o -Llib/ -lclasses
```

$(OBJ)/main.o: $(SRC)/main.cpp

```
$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(SRC)/main.cpp -o $(OBJ)/main.o
```

$(OBJ)/classA.o: $(SRC)/classA.cpp $(INC)/classA.h $(INC)/classB.h

```
$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(SRC)/classA.cpp -o $(OBJ)/classA.o
```

$(OBJ)/classB.o: $(SRC)/classB.cpp $(INC)/classB.h

```
$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(SRC)/classB.cpp -o $(OBJ)/classB.o
```

$(LIB)/libclasses.a: $(OBJ)/classA.o

```
ar rsv $(LIB)/libclasses.a $(OBJ)/classA.o
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile, much less run and crash. Please post code that you have determined actually exhibits the problematic behaviour. Don't retype from memory, use copy and paste.

Comment: And don't `#include` .cpp files.

Comment: inline ClassB *getClassBObject(return &ptr_classb;); ---> you are returning  address of pointer of ClassB type. You actually should just return ClassB *. Like this inline ClassB* getClassBObject(return this->ptr_classb;)

Comment: replace `inline ClassB getClassB(){return this->ptr_classB;}` with `inline ClassB getClassB(){return *(this->ptr_classB);}`

Comment: @Guiroux still segfault

Comment: @BlackB0ltz I just don't know what to say, i tested it (multiple files version), and after correcting once again to just be able to compile ( `ClassB.cpp` and `classB.cpp` are obviously different ), it worked like charm

Comment: @orbitcowboy I will check thanks m8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned code :

```
class ClassA ;
class ClassB ;

class ClassB{
private:
    int n;
public:
    ClassB();
    inline void set_n(int n){this->n =n;}
    inline int get_n(){return this->n;}

};

class ClassA{
private:
    ClassB *ptr_classb;
public:
    ClassA();
    inline ClassB getClassBObject(){return *ptr_classb;}
};

ClassB::ClassB(){
    this->n = 0;
}

ClassA::ClassA(){
    ptr_classb = new ClassB();
}

#include <iostream>

int main(){
    ClassA *ptr_classA = new ClassA();

    std::cout << ptr_classA->getClassBObject().get_n() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

compile and execute fine after correcting errors at COMPIL time, which make me wonder : how in hell did you manage to compile this to got segfault ?

Comment: with your code no, with mine yes, but it's the same code xD if i upload my files you will see them?

Comment: what do you mean ? upload where ?

Comment: I will put them here.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @BlackB0ltz Not with the code you're showing. That wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @juanchopanza it compiles well to me, I edited the original post with the makefile i'm using.

Comment: @BlackB0ltz There is simply no way that code compiles.

Comment: @juanchopanza then why it compiles? tell me why there's no way.

Comment: @BlackB0ltz It could compile if your compiler is badly broken. But the most likely scenario is that you're compiling different code to the one you posted.

Comment: @BlackB0ltz `ClassB getClassB(){return this->ptr_classB;}` is incorrect , `ClassB getClassB(){return *(this->ptr_classB);}` is correct, my compiler wouldn't compile first form

Comment: @Guiroux even with `ClassB getClassB(){return *(this->ptr_classB);}`i'm still getting segment fault. can you give me the codes so i can try if it's my compiler or my pc or whatever.

Comment: @Guiroux I just found the error, it's in the makefile. I corrected it and used `ClassB getClassB(){return *(this->ptr_classB);}` so thank you.

Comment: `$(OBJ)/main.o: $(SRC)/main.cpp

$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(SRC)/main.cpp -o $(OBJ)/main.o ` here, I forgot to add `$(LIB)/libclasses.a ` to `$(OBJ)/main.o `